# React+Node+Express app not accesible on localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a web app with React as `frontend` and node+express as `backend`.
The folder structure of app is as in the pic below (`client` folder is within the `server` folder)
[image]

The `package.json` in the `client` has the following code

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

The `package.json` in the `server` has the following code

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

When I execute `npm run dev`, I get the message the my server is running on port 8080 and the react app is also compiled successfully and can be viewed on http://localhost:3000
[image]

But when I visit http://localhost:3000, i get the following

[image]

It was working fine but when I added a `button.module.css` file, I got error from Typescript. One on the suggested solution on Stackoverflow was to create a `declaration.d.ts` file. The error is gone now but the site is not loading !!!

I don't how adding this file is the problem.
I tried to run 'npm start' within the 'client` folder

[image]

But I do not know what happens, screen switches to 'npm run dev' within the 'server` folder

[image]

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

I created 2 more react app with `npx create-react-app app --template typescript`.

- One next to `server` folder and
- one within `server` folder (next to `client` folder)

both of them worked just fine. No issue connecting to localhost:3000.

So I went comparing the contents one by one of my folder and the folders newly created. As it turns out I had deleted the files named `react-app-env.d.ts` (this file is automatically created by `npx create...`) . I deleted because its content is just `/// <reference types="react-scripts" />` and nothing else.

I have seen a lot of tutorials where they deleted all the files of the `src` folder & I though this file was 'not useful'

I have copied this file into my app folder & it works fine!!!

**Lesson Learnt** = DO NOT TOUCH what you don't understand! Especially when things are working ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you want a multi-layer architecture but in think npm is working against you.

try unnnested projects, try single repo/multi project approach.

something like this: https://github.com/sombriks/palavrim/blob/main/package.json

Comment: I am new to web development and I do not understand what you mean by `multi-layer architecture` and `try unnnested projects, try single repo/multi project approach`. This app **WAS** working fine! both `client` & `server` were working & I was even able to use the data from the server on a page on the client. Suddenly I got the error. Not sure from where. I would like to keep the current folder structure and just resolve the localhost connection error if possible. Thanks nonetheless for you answer.